What is a verb for "to hold or carry food in one’s pocket/pouch for some time"?
There is a verb in French called pocheter. Its meaning (taken from here), as well as an English translation, are as follows.

Serrer, porter pour quelque temps dans sa poche. Il ne se dit proprement qu'en parlant de certaines choses bonnes à manger, qu'on croit rendre meilleures en les portant quelque temps dans la poche.
To hold, to carry for some time in one's pocket. It is only properly said when speaking of certain things that are good to eat, which one believes makes better by carrying them for some time in the pocket.

I also have some sample phrases and sentences, as well as attempts at translation, as follows.

Example 1
Pocheter des olives, des truffes.
To ______ [some] olives, [some] truffles.


Example 2
Des pommes d'api pochetées.
[Some] ______ed lady apples.


Example 3
Le jeune homme lui présente sa carte. — « Elle est bien sale, reprit-il, elle est par trop pochetée ; veuillez m'en donner une autre ! » ajouta-t-il en la jetant. — (Honoré de Balzac, Un Prince de la Bohême, 1844)
The young man presents him his card. — "It is very dirty," replied he, "It is far too ______ed; be so kind as to give me another one!" added he, throwing it away. — (Honoré de Balzac, Un Prince de la Bohême [A Prince of Bohemia], 1844)

I have tried Wiktionary, Reverso, and WordReference.com, but there is nothing about it in English.
As I said, this word is a verb. It is spoken at a presumably normal register. Its connotation is that it refers to food, and that it is stored for a while to improve its quality, taste, etc.
Reverso Translate translates pocheter to poach, but poach means "To cook (something) in simmering or very hot liquid (usually water; sometimes wine, broth, or otherwise)," so that can’t be it. There is pocket, but pocket means “To put (something) into a pocket,” which doesn’t have the connotation referring to food. There is preserve, which means "To save from decay by the use of some preservative substance, such as sugar or salt; to season and prepare (fruits, meat, etc.) for storage." Preserve seems to be close, but it doesn’t have the meaning of keeping the good in a bag or the connotation of making it better, doesn’t it?
If there is a single word for pocheter in English, I haven’t found it yet. So I suppose a compound word or phrase would be acceptable.
I hope that someone can find a word that fits the bill.

Season, ripen, keep warm?

In English, we certainly do pocket things to keep them handy, hide them from others, and smuggle them for later. We pocket bribes, money, papers, business cards, a stranger's phone number scribbled on a paper napkin. But they don't ripen for the journey? Nu, so they don't ripen!

Your example 3 contradicts the requirement of being food. Anyway, I suggest pocket-worn as conveying that idea (pochetée).

The French word is obviously polysemous: 'carried about in a/one's pocket' the usual sense, but 'worn/soiled as a result of being constantly in one's pocket' the one in your third example (as Jack points out). Almost certainly a lexical gap in English, and the phrase request belongs on ELL.

The wording of your title suggests (implies?) that there is such a word. My intuition (I’m a native speaker of American English) is that there is none.

Noah Webster's An American Dictionary of the English Language mentions "pocheter des fruits , to mellow fruit in the pocket".

A French-English dictionary translation (Harrap's, 1980) shows that there is probably no term, and that only expressions can be used to render that idea. Moreover, the connotation relative to the preservation is missing, which would tend to make the misplaced example in the wiktionary appropriate (but then one more definition is needed, as cards, obviously, are not food). The only good solution is to make the idea relative to preservation  clear in the text (succinctly), and add  a translator's note for the first occurrence.

Harrap's Dictionary
pocheter A : To keep (sth) in one's pocket for some time.

A : archaism, ancient, in former use | désuet

He kept in his pocket for some time a few olives (by doing so their taste improved).
TN: The practice of …

The "for some time" part of the expression and the specific reference to a pocket are additional differences which make it impossible to use the verb "to pocket" (except in cases such as the Balzac example).

(SOED) 1 Put into one's pocket; confine or enclose in a small space, as in a pocket.

